# Angular google maps not showing and no error with mean stack

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, mean.io, angular-google-maps

I'm following the [Quickstart on their page](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use), but no success. I'm using mean.io.

The only things that I did different from the tutorial was on step 2. Instead of calling lodash and angular-google-maps using script tags, I added them to my `assets.json` file. But I checked and both files are in my page.

In step 3, I added the module to my the dependency to my module (I'm using the articles example as a base to this app):

```
angular.module('mean.articles', ['google-maps']);
```

The `google-map` tag in my page doesn't receive any content, like the examples in the angular-google-maps page. I also don't see any error in the console. I tried deleting my script tag importing googlemaps API and it shows an error in the console, so I assume that is loading correctly.

Comment: Try double-checking that you have a width and height on your map.

Comment: Shouldn't the dependency be `uiGmapgoogle-maps` ?